# C function returning different values while calling from main function

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I have written a program which read values from a the file. The data in the file is in following format.

```
    100       Full Name       SomeDetails.

    234       Full Name       SomeDetails
```

Following is the program which i wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 10
struct student
{
int rollno;
char name[20];
char course[25];
};

int main()
{
FILE *fptr;
fptr=fopen("records.txt","r");
struct student s[10];
int i=0,tstudent=0;
char che;
char line[100];

//SECTION : 1.1 -> READING NUMBER OF LINES

while(!feof(fptr))
{
    che=fgetc(fptr);
    if(che=='\n')
    {
        tstudent++;
    }
}

printf("Total Lines in File = %d\n",tstudent);
fclose(fptr);


    //SECTION : 1.2 -> READING RECORDS FROM FILE

fptr=fopen("records.txt","r");
char newString[20][20];
int ii,j,ctr;
j=0;
ctr=0;
for(i=0; i<tstudent; i++)
   {

       fgets(line,100,fptr);
       printf("Value of Line %d = %s",i,line);
       for(ii=0; ii<=(strlen(line)); ii++)
       {
           // if tab or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
           if(line[ii]=='\t'||line[ii]=='\0')
           {
               newString[ctr][j]='\0';
               ctr++;  //for next word
               j=0;    //for next word, init index to 0
           }
           else
           {
               newString[ctr][j]=line[ii];
               j++;
           }
       }

   }

   for(ii=0; ii < ctr; ii++)
   {
       printf("\n%s",newString[ii]);
   }

   printf("Value of ctr = %d",ctr);
   fclose(fptr);
   }
```

Above code is working fine, BUT all the code is in main function, but i want to make a separate function which can be called from main file and return me every data of file in two dimensional or one dimensional array as return value.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

I tried following CODE as a separate function.. NOT WORKING.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>

 char readfile(int tstudent,FILE* filename)
 {

 //FUNCTION TO READ RECORDS FROM FILE.

FILE *fptr;
int i,k;
char line[100];    
char newString[20][20];
int j=0,ctr=0;
fptr=fopen("records.txt","r");
for(i=0; i<tstudent; i++)
{
    fgets(line,100,fptr);
    printf("Value of Line %d = %s",i,line);
    for(k=0; k<=(strlen(line)); k++)
    {
        // if tab or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
        if(line[k]=='\t'||line[k]=='\0')
        {
            newString[ctr][j]='\0';
            ctr++;  //for next word
            j=0;    //for next word, init index to 0
        }
        else
        {
            newString[ctr][j]=line[k];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
return newString;
}
```

I defined a new variable char results[] in main function.. and tried to called the function as follows

```
 results[]=readfile(tstudent,fptr)
```

but when trying to read results.. its showing garbage

Comment: Don't show us the *working* code. Show the *non-working* one. And format it properly, please.

Comment: Two points: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). And `char che` should be `int che` because that is the type returned by `fgetc`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have added the code which i have tried as a separate function , which is not working.

Comment: `return newString;` - what I suspected. You can't return a locally defined array. Didn't look for other issues.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i defined a new variable char results[] in main function.. and tried to called the function as  results[]=readfile(tstudent,fptr).. but when trying to read results.. its showing garbage.

Answer (score 1):

```
char readfile(int tstudent,FILE* filename)
   ...
   char newString[20][20];
   ...
   return newString;
```

That can't be a good thing, right?  You define `readFile` to return one single character (not a pointer, just one byte) and then return an array instead.  We should not be surprised the compiler complained.

If you "fix" that be redefining the return type, you still have a problem because `newString` is an automatic local variable.  The storage (memory) it defines is undefined outside the function.

The easiest way for a function to populate a structure (or array) in C is for the caller to pass it as a function parameter.  So you wind up with something more like:

```
int readfile( FILE* input, char newString[][20], int tstudent )
```

where `newString` is defined the same way as you have it, but by the caller, not in readfile.  Cf. the stdio functions like `fgets`; most of them require the caller to define the buffer they read into.

I'll just point out a few more mistakes.

Whenever you call a function -- especially an I/O function -- check for errors.  You may want to read `tstudent` records, but how many are there?  If you ask for 5 and find only 1, what then?  Your read loop *must* test for end-of-file, and readfile must return the number of records read, else the caller will never know.  Compare with how **fread**(3) works.  Those Unix guys knew a thing or two about how to define a function!

Now your function looks something like this:

```
int readfile( FILE* input, char newString[][20], int tstudent ) {
  char line[100], *s;
  int i=0;

  for( ; i < tstudent && (s = fgets(line, sizeof(line), input)) != NULL; i++ ) {
    /* do stuff with line */ 
  }
  /* check for EOF/error if s is NULL, and report */
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Can you plz explain me what i am supposed to do with the code in simple word plz.. i am just a new student of C.

Comment: I used the simplest language I know how, Mohd.  It took time to write; if you want to understand, many of the answers are there.  One more thought that might help: you seem to be under the impression you can return an array from a function in C.  You can't.  The array should be defined in main and passed to the function.  You *can* return a pointer to a dynamically allocated array (using malloc) but that's more advanced and not necessary here.

Comment: Thank you so much, for clearing doubt that we can not return an array from a function as its return value. I hope you understand that i am just new to C (in fact new to whole programming world). So as per your suggestions, i should define an array in main function, and should pass it as arguments in the readFile function.. please let me know if we can return the same array as return value?? or how to achieve the goal?

Comment: Just like with fgets: your function receives the buffer as a parameter, fills it in, and returns.  It filled the buffer, and the caller will see that the buffer was filled.  It must, because it's the same buffer.  It might have one name in main and another in readfile, but it's the same buffer.  Technically, what's passed isn't "the buffer" but a pointer; in CS that's known generically as "pass by reference". Use the return value to show how many were read.